# Css and image from public folder don't load on when deploying node app to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I've tried suggestions from other posts with similar problems but I haven't had any luck.

For some reason everything works fine locally but won't load when I push to Heroku. Thanks in advance.
Here is the code https://github.com/DaleLuce/newsletter-signup

My understanding is that this code from my app.js

```
app.use(express.static("public"));
```

Should grab the css image. Here is the relevant code from my signup.html

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

  <img class="mb-4" src="images/img_0959.jpeg" alt="" width="144" height="144">
```

Comment: The folder in the example are Uppercase and your code path is lowercase.
Im no expert for Heroku but are the using a case sensitive file system?!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I had changed it locally but I didn't notice it wasn't changing the case of the public folder when  I  pushed the changes to github. I deleted everything and re-uploaded it and it's working. I wonder why it wasn't changing that? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The public folder was "Public"

I changed it locally but for some reason it wasn't changing on github. I deleted  and re-uploaded it and its working.